# facebook me/home API return empty Array : facebook-ios-sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iphone-sdk-3.2

I am working with facebook-ios-sdk, It working fine
But I am facing issue related to **me/home** API. It giving empty array in that case.
But When I logged-in with different facebook account then it return proper array.

First I through that it may be temporary API issue but it fetch all data for another account. It was working fine with this account too till last week.
What is this issue. If anybody know please help.

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved

may be there was no update in particular account ..